# $() not working in jsp file

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a Controller called Leave Controller which looks as follows.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class LeaveController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView loginPage()
{
    return new ModelAndView("jsp/login.jsp", "command", new Employee());
}

@RequestMapping(value="verify" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String verify(Employee eform,ModelMap model)
 {
    System.out.println(EmployeeAccessService.verify(eform));
    model.addAttribute("uname",eform.getName());
    model.addAttribute("pass",eform.getPassword());

    return "jsp/home.jsp";  
 }
}
```

The method login.jsp page sends an Employee pojo received as 'eform'. I add the two attributes to (ModelMap)model before going to home.jsp page.

Here is my home.jsp page.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
$(uname)<br>
$(pass)
</body>
</html>
```

The thing is the $(uname) and $(pass) are displayed as text instead of variables. How do I display them as variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `$()`, it's `${}`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    ${uname}<br>
    ${pass}
  </body>
</html>
```